# Flutter Error-(Valid value range is empty: 0)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use contacts_service plugin to display my contacts. I am using a Listview.Builder to build the widgets.

Although I'm using setState to update the value of the empty List, still getting a range error.

I am storing my Contacts in List contacts.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'home_screen';
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Contact> contacts = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllContacts();
  }

  getAllContacts() async {
    List<Contact> _contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false)).toList();
    setState(() {
      contacts = _contacts;
      print(contacts.length);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int length = contacts.length;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                Contact contact = contacts[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(contact.displayName),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    contact.phones.elementAt(0).value,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error i am getting.

```
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/array.dart:16:52)
#1      ListMixin.elementAt (dart:collection/list.dart:61:33)
#2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:417:40)
#3      _HomeScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:messagingflutter/screens/home_screen.dart:41:36)
#4      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:446:22)
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked for permission to read contacts as per https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service#-example-tab- ?

Comment: Yes, i am able to output contacts to the console without a Listview Builder